# Display HTML docs on web page

Tags: html, embed, dom

I have several html files eg. a.html, b.html (the type of file is chrome html document). I have another html page where I want to display this document as it is. Right now it loses its alignment and is displayed as text. I want to display it in the original format and  design. How do I do this ?>
To give you an idea[click here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jHMt8Mu7uPF3Q_WsZbZ37xUO2CXKaFNIrvHdJqi-2NE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you show any code or screenshots? You're question needs to be much clearer!

Comment: i have given the link above.

Comment: I have give the link. Can I use iframe for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an iframe?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just insert an iFrame with the other HTML document as the source, and it will display the contents of that HTML file where you place it, in its own window.

```
<iframe src="c.html" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

You'll need to adjust the height so it doesn't clip off any of your external HTML document, but doesn't leave too much whitespace.